# Calling Java Function from XSLT gives "Could not compile stylesheet"

Tags: xslt

I've gone through all the post of similar issues, but couldn't resolve my problem. I've XSLT as shown below:

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:proxy="java:com.hp.gpp.pp.util.UrlUtils"
    extension-element-prefixes="proxy">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="proxy" />
    <xsl:variable name="baseurl"
        select="/html/head/base/@href"/>

    <!-- copy input to output -->
    <xsl:template match='*|@*'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='node()|@*' />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@href]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of
                select="proxy:rewriteRelative($proxy,$baseurl,@href)" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*[name(.)!='href']" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@src]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of
                select="proxy:rewriteRelative($proxy,$baseurl,@src)" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*[name(.)!='src']" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- rewrite <a href> -->
    <xsl:template match="base">
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And a Java code as:

```
XSLTemplateFactory templateFactory = new DefaultTemplateFactory();
            Templates templates = templateFactory.getTemplatesFromURL(XSS_FILE_NAME);
Source xmlStrim = new StreamSource(reader);
Result oStream = new StreamResult(res.getWriter());

Transformer transformer = templates.newTransformer();
transformer.setParameter("proxy", new UrlUtils(req, res));
transformer.transform(xmlStrim, oStream);
```

Somehow, the code works locally but while deploying on Jboss gives:

```
ERROR:  'The first argument to the non-static Java function 'rewriteRelative' is not a valid object reference.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
com.hp.gpp.pp.exception.ProxyPortletException: error.transformer : Could not compile stylesheet
```

Not able to find the issue here. Can someone help me in this?

Thanks & regards,
Rikin

Comment: Do you realise that the namespace prefix `proxy` has nothing to do with the template parameter `proxy`, right? What is `UrlUtils` and `rewriteRelative`? Is it a home-grown library?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `transformer.setParameter` call from your Java and the corresponding `<xsl:param name="proxy" />` instruction from your XSLT.

Then bind the namespace prefix to the Java class, like this

```
<xsl:script implements-prefix="proxy" language="java" src="java:com.hp.gpp.pp.util.UrlUtils"/>
```

Then you can write

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">
  <xsl:value-of select="proxy:rewriteRelative($baseurl, @href)" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

I assume `rewriteRelative` takes just two parameters: the base URL and a relative URL? I'm not clear what the previous first parameter `$proxy` was for, but I guess it doesn't belong in there.

Comment: Thanks for your response Borodin. Few Questions here:
1> As you can see that the UrlUtils class needs Request & Response objects to create object. These objects are used to rewrite the HREF URL. How will I pass those objects?
2> How the Transformer will call the methods of UrlUtils as those methods are not static - cannot keep them static. That's the reason rewriteRelative has third parameter $proxy which is set as parameter to Transformer. Is this the wrong approach or something?

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when trying to transform using an XSLT 2.0 'stylesheet', but I use an XSLT 1.0 parser.

I am not sure if this applies to your error. For this reason, I posted a separate Q&A in stackoverflow: [Why do I get the following exception 'first argument to the non-static Java function'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514919/fatal-error-the-first-argument-to-the-non-static-java-function-is-not-a-va/)