# Why do I get the following exception 'first argument to the non-static Java function'?

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I get this exception:

FATAL ERROR: 'The first argument to the non-static Java function *** is not a valid object reference.'

This happens when I try to transform an XML document using the xml-maven-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>transform</goal>
           </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <transformationSets>
            <transformationSet>
                <dir>target/generated/wsdl</dir>
                <stylesheet>src/test/resources/transform/my-transformation.xsl</stylesheet> 
                <includes>   
                    <include>**/*.xsd</include>
                </includes>
                <outputDir>target/generated/wsdl</outputDir>
            </transformationSet>
         </transformationSets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Error message

```
 [INFO] --- xml-maven-plugin:1.0:transform (transform--xsd) @ my-pom ---
 Warning:  org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser: Feature 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing' is not recognized.
 Warning:  org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.
 Warning:  org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser: Property 'http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/entityExpansionLimit' is not recognized.
 ERROR:  'The first argument to the non-static Java function 'isTheRightElement' is not a valid object reference.'
 FATAL ERROR:  'The first argument to the non-static Java function 'isTheRightElement' is not a valid object reference.'
```

XSL Transformation file's content

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://mysite/mycreate" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:mytag="http://andreas/ps-transformations" version="2.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4"/>

<xsl:variable name="myAnnotations" select="document('element-list.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xs:element">     
    <xsl:param name="myValue" select="normalize-space(mytag:isTheRightElement(@class))"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$myValue=''">
            <xsl:copy> 
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:copy> 
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                <xsl:element name="xs:annotation"> 
                    <xsl:element name="xs:documentation">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$elementValue"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element> 
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:function name="myTag:isTheRightElement">
    <xsl:param name="class"/>  
       <xsl:for-each select="$myAnnotations/elementList/element">
            <xsl:if test="lower-case(@class) = 'something'">
               <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>           
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:function>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "I get this exception" is not a question. I would also recommend pulling down the error message from the title and putting it (also) in the body text

Comment: I formulated the question properly and demonstrated the whole case. It would be only fair to put a positive point, since the question raised your interest.

Comment: I'll take away my deduction as "I have this problem" is a valid question, even without a question mark. But I had trouble understanding the issue. could be I was confused/distracted. But restating your issue in the body might help people that are easily distracted.

Answer (score 3):

I get this error when trying to transform using an XSLT 2.0 'stylesheet', but I use an XSLT 1.0 parser.

In my case, this happens when I remove the maven dependency of saxon, which is an XSLT 2.0 parser. 
The XSLT parser that comes with Java 7 can handle only XSLT 1.0.

Maven solution is to keep the Saxon:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>transform</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <transformerFactory>net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl</transformerFactory>
        <transformationSets>
            <transformationSet>
                <dir>src/main/resources/xml</dir>
                <stylesheet>src/main/resources/xslt/my-transformation.xsl</stylesheet>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <outputDir>target/generated/wsdl</outputDir>
            </transformationSet>
        </transformationSets>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
            <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
            <version>9.6.0-5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: As I said in my answer, if you switch to a different XSLT processor, you can expect calls to external Java functions to work completely differently.

Comment: I know but based on the exception the processor displays it is not clear at all. Agreed, when I you use the saxon processor is works. This is what this question/answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old, but it came up on my feed as a result of a new comment, and it hasn't been properly answered, so here goes.

The stylesheet uses `xsl:function`, and specifies version="2.0", but is being run using an XSLT 1.0 processor. According to the rules of XSLT 1.0, if the version is greater than 1.0, then it runs in "forwards compatibility mode" (FCM). In FCM, any top-level declarations not defined in XSLT 1.0 are ignored; so the `xsl:function` declaration has no effect, it is simply ignored. So how does Xalan handle the function call `mytag:isTheRightElement(@class)`? It's not a call to a built-in function, so the only thing it can be is a call to a (Java) extension function. So Xalan tries to interpret it as a call-out to Java, and fails, because, as it says "The first argument ... is not a valid object reference".

Yes, it's an error message that doesn't get anywhere near the real cause of the problem. Standing back a bit, when you design error messages, you've got to try and work out what the user was trying to do. Xalan thinks the user was trying to call out to Java, and it was wrong. But how could the designers of Xalan, years before XSLT 2.0 was specified, have guessed the true reason?

FCM has not been the most successful feature of XSLT's design. The idea (at a time when people assumed XSLT would be widely used in the browser, and that lots of users would be using rather old browsers) was that if you pointed an old browser that only supported XSLT 1.0 at a web site that used a more up-to-date version, then you would get some kind of sensible fallback behaviour. But as this example shows, simply ignoring the `xsl:function` declaration doesn't stop the stylesheet failing, and it would have given a clearer error message if the `xsl:function` declaration had simply been rejected as invalid. Predicting the future is not easy.

Answer (score -1):

Handling of calls from XSLT to Java is not defined in any standard - it depends entirely on which XSLT processor you are using.

Note also, if you're using Saxon, version 8.7 is VERY old (about 2006). The current version is 9.6.

Comment: The version of saxon is irrelevant, but I still put the latest version, in case someone blindly copies the code.
I just display how to fix the exception (in this case at least). No online source helped me when I got the exception, although many similar questions exist in the web.

Comment: The question wasn't about calling a java function but a custom function. It's a wildly misleading error message when you try to execute an XSLT 2.0 file with a XLST 1.0 parser.

Answer (score -1):

For me it was just a silly mistake of forgetting to add the called java class to the classpath. In eclipse you can do that under Run --> Run Configurations... --> Classpath tab and adding the right java class.